# html2canvas save to phone gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

Im creating a website that has a downloadable div that produces a pdf if the client is ung a desktop or an image if the user is on mobile.

It uses html2canvas to convert the div to an image and allows the user to download it, its works and the image is succesfully downloaded to the downloads folder, the problem is that the client wants the image to go directly to the client's phone gallery, is there a way to do that? im using jquery and html2canvas for this, here's the working code for saving the image to download folder

```
let jQueryNC = jQuery.noConflict();

jQueryNC('#save-voucher-img').click(function () {

    jQueryNC('#save-voucher-img').addClass("removed");

    html2canvas(jQueryNC("#voucher-code-form")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
        let jQueryNC = jQuery.noConflict();
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        saveAs(imgData, 'event-voucher.jpg');
    });

    jQueryNC('#save-voucher-img').removeClass("removed");
});
```